# Can't find the launch CSM option

Tags: 18.04, windows, asus

almuhanamalik

Hello I am trying to install Ubuntu Linux 18.04 on my laptop. everything was good until I had to boot it from the USB in the bios. I read online that I have to enable the launch CSM and disable the secure boot I disabled the secure boot but unfortunately in the boot configuration I cant find the launch CSM I only have the fast boot option.

my laptop is Asus E200HA
Bios version 303
GOP version 8.0.1033

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try reading Try reading https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI .  Turning off secure boot is really not necessary in most cases, and for your installation to be in the same mode Windows is in (UEFI?), you have to boot the USB install media in UEFI mode